# Errors caused by adding Mahout Dependency to Gradle

Tags: java, hadoop, gradle, mahout

I am trying to run a hadoop job using gradle to build my project and when I add the mahout dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-core', version: '3.1.2'

    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-common', version: '3.1.2'

    compile group: 'org.apache.mahout', name: 'mahout-hdfs', version: '0.13.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.mahout', name: 'mahout-mr', version: '0.13.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.mahout', name: 'mahout-math', version: '0.13.0'
}

jar {
    from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}

ext.hadoopVersion = "3.1.2"
```

to my build file I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem cannot access its superinterface org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.TokenAspect$TokenManagementDelegator
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:3217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.addInputPath(FileInputFormat.java:542)
    at ConvertText.ConvertTextJob.main(ConvertTextJob.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:232)
```

but without this mahout dependency the job works just fine.

Here is the code where I am using the library:

```
package ConvertText;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable;

public class ConvertTextJob {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
      //Setup for the first job
      Configuration conf = new Configuration();

      //Setup for jar of class
      Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Convert Text");
      job.setJarByClass(ConvertTextJob.class);

      // path to input/output in HDFS
      FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

      //Set Mapper class
      job.setMapperClass(ConvertTextMapper.class);

      // Outputs from the Mapper
      job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
      job.setOutputValueClass(VectorWritable.class);

      //Set format of the key/value format
      job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

      job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

      // Block until the job is completed.
      System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

}
```

Does anyone know what the issue is and how I can fix it so I can use the dependency? I am doing a project that involves mahout and requires this dependency.

Comment: Could you please post a code sample, so that we know how you are using the library and where you are getting the error?

Comment: At the very least `VectorWritable` depends on `HDFS`.  Yes just add the dependency in your gradle build, the `spark` and i believe  `mahout-mr` modules will both depend on ity as well.

Answer (score 0):

the `hdfs` module was factored out of mahout-core in `mahout-0.13.0`.

https://github.com/apache/mahout/tree/mahout-0.13.0

```
~ > mahout > mahout-0.13.0 > 7? > $ > ls 
  100-interpreter-spec.yaml       LICENSE.txt           NOTICE.txt
  README.md                       bin/                  buildtools/
  community/                      conf/                 core/
  distribution/                   doap_Mahout.rdf       docs/
  dry_run.sh                      engine/               examples/
  experimental/                   flink/                h2o/
  hdfs/                           integration/          issuse
  lib/                            mahout.iml            math/
  math-scala/                     mr/                   pom.xml
  resource-managers/              runtests.sh           scratch
  spark/                          src/                  target/
  viennacl/                       viennacl-omp/
```

you'll have to add the `mahout-hdfs` arifact to build for 0.13.0.

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.mahout/mahout-hdfs
compile group: 'org.apache.mahout', name: 'mahout-hdfs', version: '0.13.0'
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.mahout/mahout-hdfs/0.13.0

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I added all the dependencies you suggested (I added my full build file to the question) and am still having the same error. Do you know if there are anymore that could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find and remove/exclude `hadoop-hdfs-2.x.x.jar` from the classpath. It's clashing with the newer version of HDFS pulled in by Mahout.